# Изменить буферизацию потока ввода из консоли

Tags: c, gcc

Использую код для stdio.h:

```
 int c;    
 while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
 {
     printf("%c", c);
 }
```

Набранные в консоли символы выводятся программой только после нажатия Enter. Как, используя getchar() и printf(), выводить на экран символ сразу после нажатия клавиши, не дожидаясь нажатия Enter, и завершать работу программы при вводе EOF?

Comment: Вы хотите, наверное, аналог *kbdhit()* из DOS, но такого переносимого решения нет, определяется в *nix настройками порта консоли через termios. А лучше просто использовать специализированные библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
        struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
        unsigned char c;

        /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&old_tio);

        /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
        new_tio=old_tio;

        /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
        new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);

        /* set the new settings immediately */
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);

        do {
                 c=getchar();
                 printf("%c ",c);
        } while(c!='q');

        /* restore the former settings */
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);

        return 0;
}
```